# bind a listener to each row, jquery

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsp

I am trying to bind a piece of jquery to each row of a table.  When the configured checkbox is checked it should enable or disable all the components on each row.  Heres the code i have so far.  By default any row that isn't configured has all its components disabled.  They problem I'm having is turning each row on individually.

my attempt

```
 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function enableAction(configured) {
        if (configured == true) {
            $(".checkbox").attr("disabled", false);
        } else {
            $(".checkbox").attr("disabled", true);
        }
    }
    </script>
```

When this checkbox is selected it should enable any checkboxes, textfields or combo boxes currently residing in that row.

```
<%-- "Configured" column --%>
    <td>
        <c:choose>
            <c:when test="${policy.required}">
                <aep-form:checkbox id="configuredCheckBox" path="policiesList[${policyKey}].configured" disabled="true" readonly="true" value="true"
                onclick="enableAction(${policy.configured })"/>
            </c:when>
            <c:otherwise>
                <aep-form:checkbox id="configuredCheckBox" path="policiesList[${policyKey}].configured"/>
            </c:otherwise>
        </c:choose>
    </td>
```

These are all the components that need to be enabled or disabled.

```
<c:choose>

    <c:when test="${policyValue.type eq 'CHECKBOX'}">
        <aep-form:checkbox id="checkbox" path="policiesList[${policyKey}].policyValueViews[${policyValueKey}].valueAsBoolean"
        disabled="${!isConfigured}"/>
        <span class="${overrideClass}">${policyValue.name}</span>
        <br/>
    </c:when>

    <c:when test="${policyValue.type eq 'CHOICE'}">
        <div class="${overrideClass}">${policyValue.name}</div>
        <form:select path="policiesList[${policyKey}].policyValueViews[${policyValueKey}].value"
        disabled="${!policy.configured }">
            <form:options items="${policyValue.valueList}" />
        </form:select>
        </c:when>

            <c:when test="${(policyValue.type eq 'CURRENCY') || (policyValue.type eq 'INTEGER')}">
                <div class="${overrideClass}">${policyValue.name}</div>
                <form:input path="policiesList[${policyKey}].policyValueViews[${policyValueKey}].value" cssClass="${policyValueError}"
                disabled="${!policy.configured}"  />
            </c:when>

            <c:when test="${(policyValue.type eq 'CSV') || (policyValue.type eq 'TEXT')}">
                <div class="${overrideClass}">${policyValue.name}</div>
                <aep-form:textarea path="policiesList[${policyKey}].policyValueViews[${policyValueKey}].value" cssClass="${policyValueError}"  cols="20" rows="3"
                disabled="${!policy.configured}"/>
            </c:when>

            <c:otherwise>
                <div class="${overrideClass}">${policyValue.name}</div>
                <aep-form:textarea path="policiesList[${policyKey}].policyValueViews[${policyValueKey}].value" cssClass="${policyValueError}"  cols="20" rows="3"
                disabled="${!policy.configured}"/>
            </c:otherwise>
        </c:choose>
        </c:forEach>
```

Rendered HTML

```
<div id="tws-prm-partner-sla-information-application-policies">



            <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
            function enableAction(configured){
                if(configured == true){
                    $(".checkbox").attr("disabled",false);
                }else{
                    $(".checkbox").attr("disabled", true);
                }
            }
            </script>

           <fieldset>
             <legend>Policies : SMS_Send-Sandbox-OneAPI_REST_v2_0</legend>


             <div id="application-policies">
              <table id="tws-prm-partner-sla-information-application-policies-list" class="dataSummaryTable">
                  <thead>
                      <tr>
                          <th title="A policy must be configured before it is enabled on the SLA.">Configured</th>

                          <th>Key</th>
                          <th title="Configuration values for the policy. Each policy takes its own unique set of values, refer to the administration documentation for advice.">Values</th>
                      </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>

                      <tr>

                          <td>


                                      <input id="configuredCheckBox" name="policiesList[Application State].configured" class="checkboxDefault" onclick="enableAction(true)" disabled="disabled" readonly="readonly" type="checkbox" value="true" checked="checked"/>

                          </td>
                          <td><span title="Application State for a service.">Application State</span></td>



                          <td>

                                      <div class="isDefault">Application State</div>
                                      <select id="policiesListApplication State.policyValueViewsApplication State.value" name="policiesList[Application State].policyValueViews[Application State].value">
                                          <option value="sandbox" selected="selected">sandbox</option><option value="limited live">limited live</option><option value="production">production</option>

                                      </select>

                          </td>
                      </tr>





                      <tr>

                          <td>



                                      <input id="configuredCheckBox" name="policiesList[Authorization].configured" class="checkboxDefault" type="checkbox" value="true"/><input type="hidden" name="_policiesList[Authorization].configured" value="on"/>


                          </td>
                          <td><span title="Allows service requests to authorized subscribers only">Authorization</span></td>



                          <td>


                          </td>
                      </tr>





                      <tr>

                          <td>



                                      <input id="configuredCheckBox" name="policiesList[Default Sender Address].configured" class="checkboxDefault" type="checkbox" value="true"/><input type="hidden" name="_policiesList[Default Sender Address].configured" value="on"/>


                          </td>

                          <td><span title="The default sender address for a subscriber can be set within this policy">Default Sender Address</span></td>



                          <td>


                                      <div class="isDefault">Default Address</div>
                                      <textarea id="policiesListDefault Sender Address.policyValueViewsDefault Address.value" name="policiesList[Default Sender Address].policyValueViews[Default Address].value" class="policyValueMap" disabled="disabled" rows="3" cols="20">tel:12345</textarea>

                          </td>
                      </tr>


                      <tr>

                          <td>



                                      <input id="configuredCheckBox" name="policiesList[Destination Address Blacklist].configured" class="checkboxDefault" type="checkbox" value="true"/><input type="hidden" name="_policiesList[Destination Address Blacklist].configured" value="on"/>


                          </td>
                          <td><span title="Forbids service requests to addresses on a black list">Destination Address Blacklist</span></td>



                          <td>


                                      <div class="isDefault">Destination Address Blacklist</div>

                                      <textarea id="policiesListDestination Address Blacklist.policyValueViewsDestination Address Blacklist.value" name="policiesList[Destination Address Blacklist].policyValueViews[Destination Address Blacklist].value" class="policyValueMap" disabled="disabled" rows="3" cols="20"></textarea>





                          </td>
                      </tr>





                      <tr>

                          <td>



                                      <input id="configuredCheckBox" name="policiesList[Destination Address Whitelist].configured" class="checkboxDefault" type="checkbox" value="true"/><input type="hidden" name="_policiesList[Destination Address Whitelist].configured" value="on"/>


                          </td>
                          <td><span title="Forbids service requests to addresses not on a white list">Destination Address Whitelist</span></td>



                          <td>                            
                                      <div class="isDefault">Destination Address Whitelist</div>
                                      <textarea id="policiesListDestination Address Whitelist.policyValueViewsDestination Address Whitelist.value" name="policiesList[Destination Address Whitelist].policyValueViews[Destination Address Whitelist].value" class="policyValueMap" disabled="disabled" rows="3" cols="20"></textarea>

                          </td>
                      </tr>





                      <tr>


                          <td>


                                      <input id="configuredCheckBox" name="policiesList[Is Receipting Enabled?].configured" class="checkboxDefault" onclick="enableAction(true)" disabled="disabled" readonly="readonly" type="checkbox" value="true" checked="checked"/>



                          </td>
                          <td><span title="Can partner use receipting?">Is Receipting Enabled?</span></td>



                          <td>                            
                                      <div class="isDefault">Is Receipting Enabled?</div>

                                      <select id="policiesListIs Receipting Enabled?.policyValueViewsIs Receipting Enabled?.value" name="policiesList[Is Receipting Enabled?].policyValueViews[Is Receipting Enabled?].value">
                                          <option value="yes">yes</option><option value="no" selected="selected">no</option>
                                      </select>

                          </td>
                      </tr>





                      <tr>

                          <td>



                                      <input id="configuredCheckBox" name="policiesList[Max Destination Addresses].configured" class="checkboxDefault" type="checkbox" value="true"/><input type="hidden" name="_policiesList[Max Destination Addresses].configured" value="on"/>



                          </td>
                          <td><span title="Maximum number of addresses that can be send on an address">Max Destination Addresses</span></td>



                          <td>                              


                                      <div class="isDefault">Max Destination Addresses</div>
                                      <input id="policiesListMax Destination Addresses.policyValueViewsMax Destination Addresses.value" name="policiesList[Max Destination Addresses].policyValueViews[Max Destination Addresses].value" class="policyValueMap" disabled="disabled" type="text" value="100"/>                                               
                          </td>

                      </tr>





                      <tr>

                          <td>



                                      <input id="configuredCheckBox" name="policiesList[Max Transactions Per Interval].configured" class="checkboxDefault" type="checkbox" value="true"/><input type="hidden" name="_policiesList[Max Transactions Per Interval].configured" value="on"/>


                          </td>
                          <td><span title="Maximum number of transactions per interval">Max Transactions Per Interval</span></td>



                          <td>

                                      <div class="isDefault">Interval (in milliseconds)</div>
                                      <input id="policiesListMax Transactions Per Interval.policyValueViewsInterval (in milliseconds).value" name="policiesList[Max Transactions Per Interval].policyValueViews[Interval (in milliseconds)].value" class="policyValueMap" disabled="disabled" type="text" value="1000"/>



                                      <div class="isDefault">Transactions per Interval</div>
                                      <input id="policiesListMax Transactions Per Interval.policyValueViewsTransactions per Interval.value" name="policiesList[Max Transactions Per Interval].policyValueViews[Transactions per Interval].value" class="policyValueMap" disabled="disabled" type="text" value="150"/>                                

                          </td>
                      </tr>





                      <tr>


                          <td>



                                      <input id="configuredCheckBox" name="policiesList[Maximum SMS Length].configured" class="checkboxDefault" type="checkbox" value="true"/><input type="hidden" name="_policiesList[Maximum SMS Length].configured" value="on"/>


                          </td>
                          <td><span title="Maximum length of message which can be sent over SMS">Maximum SMS Length</span></td>



                          <td>                                

                                      <div class="isDefault">Maximum SMS Length</div>

                                      <input id="policiesListMaximum SMS Length.policyValueViewsMaximum SMS Length.value" name="policiesList[Maximum SMS Length].policyValueViews[Maximum SMS Length].value" class="policyValueMap" disabled="disabled" type="text" value="320"/>                           

                          </td>
                      </tr>





                      <tr>

                          <td>



                                      <input id="configuredCheckBox" name="policiesList[Maximum Transactions].configured" class="checkboxDefault" type="checkbox" value="true"/><input type="hidden" name="_policiesList[Maximum Transactions].configured" value="on"/>


                          </td>
                          <td><span title="Maximum number of transactions allowed">Maximum Transactions</span></td>                          
                          <td>

                                      <div class="isDefault">Maximum Transactions</div>
                                      <input id="policiesListMaximum Transactions.policyValueViewsMaximum Transactions.value" name="policiesList[Maximum Transactions].policyValueViews[Maximum Transactions].value" class="policyValueMap" disabled="disabled" type="text" value="1000"/>                       

                          </td>
                      </tr>





                      <tr>

                          <td>                

                                      <input id="configuredCheckBox" name="policiesList[Minimum SMS Length].configured" class="checkboxDefault" type="checkbox" value="true"/><input type="hidden" name="_policiesList[Minimum SMS Length].configured" value="on"/>


                          </td>
                          <td><span title="Minimum length of message which can be sent over SMS">Minimum SMS Length</span></td>



                          <td>


                                      <div class="isDefault">Minimum SMS Length</div>
                                      <input id="policiesListMinimum SMS Length.policyValueViewsMinimum SMS Length.value" name="policiesList[Minimum SMS Length].policyValueViews[Minimum SMS Length].value" class="policyValueMap" disabled="disabled" type="text" value="1"/>

                          </td>
                      </tr>





                      <tr>

                          <td>



                                      <input id="configuredCheckBox" name="policiesList[Operation Set].configured" class="checkboxDefault" type="checkbox" value="true"/><input type="hidden" name="_policiesList[Operation Set].configured" value="on"/>


                          </td>
                          <td><span title="Allows service requests to specified operations only">Operation Set</span></td>



                          <td>



                                    <input id="checkbox" name="policiesList[Operation Set].policyValueViews[getSmsDeliveryStatus].valueAsBoolean" class="checkboxDefault" disabled="disabled" type="checkbox" value="true" checked="checked"/>
                                    <span class="isDefault">getSmsDeliveryStatus</span>
                                    <br/>


                                    <input id="checkbox" name="policiesList[Operation Set].policyValueViews[sendSms].valueAsBoolean" class="checkboxDefault" disabled="disabled" type="checkbox" value="true" checked="checked"/>
                                    <span class="isDefault">sendSms</span>
                                    <br/>



                                    <input id="checkbox" name="policiesList[Operation Set].policyValueViews[sendSmsLogo].valueAsBoolean" class="checkboxDefault" disabled="disabled" type="checkbox" value="true" checked="checked"/>
                                    <span class="isDefault">sendSmsLogo</span>
                                    <br/>

                                    <input id="checkbox" name="policiesList[Operation Set].policyValueViews[sendSmsRingtone].valueAsBoolean" class="checkboxDefault" disabled="disabled" type="checkbox" value="true" checked="checked"/>
                                    <span class="isDefault">sendSmsRingtone</span>
                                    <br/>                                 


                          </td>
                      </tr>                     

                      <tr>

                          <td>



                                      <input id="configuredCheckBox" name="policiesList[Prepaid Charging Configuration].configured" class="checkboxDefault" type="checkbox" value="true"/><input type="hidden" name="_policiesList[Prepaid Charging Configuration].configured" value="on"/>


                          </td>
                          <td><span title="Prepaid Charging Configuration">Prepaid Charging Configuration</span></td>



                          <td>

                                      <div class="isDefault">account_label</div>

                                      <textarea id="policiesListPrepaid Charging Configuration.policyValueViewsaccount_label.value" name="policiesList[Prepaid Charging Configuration].policyValueViews[account_label].value" class="policyValueMap" disabled="disabled" rows="3" cols="20">PRIMARY</textarea>



                                      <div class="isDefault">account_type</div>
                                      <textarea id="policiesListPrepaid Charging Configuration.policyValueViewsaccount_type.value" name="policiesList[Prepaid Charging Configuration].policyValueViews[account_type].value" class="policyValueMap" disabled="disabled" rows="3" cols="20">STORED_VALUE</textarea>


                                      <div class="isDefault">sendSms</div>
                                      <textarea id="policiesListPrepaid Charging Configuration.policyValueViewssendSms.value" name="policiesList[Prepaid Charging Configuration].policyValueViews[sendSms].value" class="policyValueMap" disabled="disabled" rows="3" cols="20">10</textarea>

                          </td>

                      </tr>


                      <tr>

                          <td>



                                      <input id="configuredCheckBox" name="policiesList[Sender Address Blacklist].configured" class="checkboxDefault" type="checkbox" value="true"/><input type="hidden" name="_policiesList[Sender Address Blacklist].configured" value="on"/>


                          </td>
                          <td><span title="Forbids service requests with argument on a black list">Sender Address Blacklist</span></td>

                                      <div class="isDefault">Sender Address Blacklist</div>
                                      <textarea id="policiesListSender Address Blacklist.policyValueViewsSender Address Blacklist.value" name="policiesList[Sender Address Blacklist].policyValueViews[Sender Address Blacklist].value" class="policyValueMap" disabled="disabled" rows="3" cols="20"></textarea>                              

                          </td>
                      </tr>


                      <tr>

                          <td>

                                      <input id="configuredCheckBox" name="policiesList[Sender Address Whitelist].configured" class="checkboxDefault" type="checkbox" value="true"/><input type="hidden" name="_policiesList[Sender Address Whitelist].configured" value="on"/>                           
                          </td>
                          <td><span title="Forbids service requests with argument not on a white list">Sender Address Whitelist</span></td>

                          <td>

                                      <div class="isDefault">Sender Address Whitelist</div>
                                      <textarea id="policiesListSender Address Whitelist.policyValueViewsSender Address Whitelist.value" name="policiesList[Sender Address Whitelist].policyValueViews[Sender Address Whitelist].value" class="policyValueMap" disabled="disabled" rows="3" cols="20"></textarea>            

                          </td>

                      </tr>

                </tbody>
              </table>
             </div>

           </fieldset>

   </div>
```

Comment: Please post the rendered html code - that will be better to find the correct way with jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

First you should not use "configuredCheckBox" as the "ID", as ID should be only one. replace it with a class. 
Then your jquery code should be something like the following

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
    $(".configuredCheckBox").live("change",function(){$(this).closest("tr").find("input,textarea").attr("disabled",$(this).is(":checked") ? null : "disabled"); $(this).attr("disabled",null)});
    })
</script>
```

The code above binds all 'change' events of elements matching `".configuredCheckBox"` selector (present or future) to a function that find the wrapping table row (closest), and then find the nested input/textarea elements in that row, and disabled/enables them according to checkbox value.

Later, it makes sure the checkbox itself is always enabled.

You can copy/paste the following code which is your rendered HTML + id-class modification I was talking about + the javascript and see it in action .

```
<table id="tws-prm-partner-sla-information-application-policies-list" class="dataSummaryTable" border=1>
                  <thead>
                      <tr>
                          <th title="A policy must be configured before it is enabled on the SLA.">Configured</th>

                          <th>Key</th>
                          <th title="Configuration values for the policy. Each policy takes its own unique set of values, refer to the administration documentation for advice.">Values</th>
                      </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>

                      <tr>

                          <td>


                                      <input class="configuredCheckBox" name="policiesList[Application State].configured" class="checkboxDefault" onclick="enableAction(true)" disabled="disabled" readonly="readonly" type="checkbox" value="true" checked="checked"/>

                          </td>
                          <td><span title="Application State for a service.">Application State</span></td>



                          <td>

                                      <div class="isDefault">Application State</div>
                                      <select id="policiesListApplication State.policyValueViewsApplication State.value" name="policiesList[Application State].policyValueViews[Application State].value">
                                          <option value="sandbox" selected="selected">sandbox</option><option value="limited live">limited live</option><option value="production">production</option>

                                      </select>

                          </td>
                      </tr>





                      <tr>

                          <td>



                                      <input class="configuredCheckBox" name="policiesList[Authorization].configured" class="checkboxDefault" type="checkbox" value="true"/><input type="hidden" name="_policiesList[Authorization].configured" value="on"/>


                          </td>
                          <td><span title="Allows service requests to authorized subscribers only">Authorization</span></td>



                          <td>


                          </td>
                      </tr>





                      <tr>

                          <td>



                                      <input class="configuredCheckBox" name="policiesList[Default Sender Address].configured" class="checkboxDefault" type="checkbox" value="true"/><input type="hidden" name="_policiesList[Default Sender Address].configured" value="on"/>


                          </td>

                          <td><span title="The default sender address for a subscriber can be set within this policy">Default Sender Address</span></td>



                          <td>


                                      <div class="isDefault">Default Address</div>
                                      <textarea id="policiesListDefault Sender Address.policyValueViewsDefault Address.value" name="policiesList[Default Sender Address].policyValueViews[Default Address].value" class="policyValueMap" disabled="disabled" rows="3" cols="20">tel:12345</textarea>

                          </td>
                      </tr>


                      <tr>

                          <td>



                                      <input class="configuredCheckBox" name="policiesList[Destination Address Blacklist].configured" class="checkboxDefault" type="checkbox" value="true"/><input type="hidden" name="_policiesList[Destination Address Blacklist].configured" value="on"/>


                          </td>
                          <td><span title="Forbids service requests to addresses on a black list">Destination Address Blacklist</span></td>



                          <td>


                                      <div class="isDefault">Destination Address Blacklist</div>

                                      <textarea id="policiesListDestination Address Blacklist.policyValueViewsDestination Address Blacklist.value" name="policiesList[Destination Address Blacklist].policyValueViews[Destination Address Blacklist].value" class="policyValueMap" disabled="disabled" rows="3" cols="20"></textarea>





                          </td>
                      </tr>





                      <tr>

                          <td>



                                      <input class="configuredCheckBox" name="policiesList[Destination Address Whitelist].configured" class="checkboxDefault" type="checkbox" value="true"/><input type="hidden" name="_policiesList[Destination Address Whitelist].configured" value="on"/>


                          </td>
                          <td><span title="Forbids service requests to addresses not on a white list">Destination Address Whitelist</span></td>



                          <td>
                                      <div class="isDefault">Destination Address Whitelist</div>
                                      <textarea id="policiesListDestination Address Whitelist.policyValueViewsDestination Address Whitelist.value" name="policiesList[Destination Address Whitelist].policyValueViews[Destination Address Whitelist].value" class="policyValueMap" disabled="disabled" rows="3" cols="20"></textarea>

                          </td>
                      </tr>





                      <tr>


                          <td>


                                      <input class="configuredCheckBox" name="policiesList[Is Receipting Enabled?].configured" class="checkboxDefault" onclick="enableAction(true)" disabled="disabled" readonly="readonly" type="checkbox" value="true" checked="checked"/>



                          </td>
                          <td><span title="Can partner use receipting?">Is Receipting Enabled?</span></td>



                          <td>
                                      <div class="isDefault">Is Receipting Enabled?</div>

                                      <select id="policiesListIs Receipting Enabled?.policyValueViewsIs Receipting Enabled?.value" name="policiesList[Is Receipting Enabled?].policyValueViews[Is Receipting Enabled?].value">
                                          <option value="yes">yes</option><option value="no" selected="selected">no</option>
                                      </select>

                          </td>
                      </tr>





                      <tr>

                          <td>



                                      <input class="configuredCheckBox" name="policiesList[Max Destination Addresses].configured" class="checkboxDefault" type="checkbox" value="true"/><input type="hidden" name="_policiesList[Max Destination Addresses].configured" value="on"/>



                          </td>
                          <td><span title="Maximum number of addresses that can be send on an address">Max Destination Addresses</span></td>



                          <td>


                                      <div class="isDefault">Max Destination Addresses</div>
                                      <input id="policiesListMax Destination Addresses.policyValueViewsMax Destination Addresses.value" name="policiesList[Max Destination Addresses].policyValueViews[Max Destination Addresses].value" class="policyValueMap" disabled="disabled" type="text" value="100"/>
                          </td>

                      </tr>





                      <tr>

                          <td>



                                      <input class="configuredCheckBox" name="policiesList[Max Transactions Per Interval].configured" class="checkboxDefault" type="checkbox" value="true"/><input type="hidden" name="_policiesList[Max Transactions Per Interval].configured" value="on"/>


                          </td>
                          <td><span title="Maximum number of transactions per interval">Max Transactions Per Interval</span></td>



                          <td>

                                      <div class="isDefault">Interval (in milliseconds)</div>
                                      <input id="policiesListMax Transactions Per Interval.policyValueViewsInterval (in milliseconds).value" name="policiesList[Max Transactions Per Interval].policyValueViews[Interval (in milliseconds)].value" class="policyValueMap" disabled="disabled" type="text" value="1000"/>



                                      <div class="isDefault">Transactions per Interval</div>
                                      <input id="policiesListMax Transactions Per Interval.policyValueViewsTransactions per Interval.value" name="policiesList[Max Transactions Per Interval].policyValueViews[Transactions per Interval].value" class="policyValueMap" disabled="disabled" type="text" value="150"/>

                          </td>
                      </tr>





                      <tr>


                          <td>



                                      <input class="configuredCheckBox" name="policiesList[Maximum SMS Length].configured" class="checkboxDefault" type="checkbox" value="true"/><input type="hidden" name="_policiesList[Maximum SMS Length].configured" value="on"/>


                          </td>
                          <td><span title="Maximum length of message which can be sent over SMS">Maximum SMS Length</span></td>



                          <td>

                                      <div class="isDefault">Maximum SMS Length</div>

                                      <input id="policiesListMaximum SMS Length.policyValueViewsMaximum SMS Length.value" name="policiesList[Maximum SMS Length].policyValueViews[Maximum SMS Length].value" class="policyValueMap" disabled="disabled" type="text" value="320"/>

                          </td>
                      </tr>





                      <tr>

                          <td>



                                      <input class="configuredCheckBox" name="policiesList[Maximum Transactions].configured" class="checkboxDefault" type="checkbox" value="true"/><input type="hidden" name="_policiesList[Maximum Transactions].configured" value="on"/>


                          </td>
                          <td><span title="Maximum number of transactions allowed">Maximum Transactions</span></td>
                          <td>

                                      <div class="isDefault">Maximum Transactions</div>
                                      <input id="policiesListMaximum Transactions.policyValueViewsMaximum Transactions.value" name="policiesList[Maximum Transactions].policyValueViews[Maximum Transactions].value" class="policyValueMap" disabled="disabled" type="text" value="1000"/>

                          </td>
                      </tr>





                      <tr>

                          <td>

                                      <input class="configuredCheckBox" name="policiesList[Minimum SMS Length].configured" class="checkboxDefault" type="checkbox" value="true"/><input type="hidden" name="_policiesList[Minimum SMS Length].configured" value="on"/>


                          </td>
                          <td><span title="Minimum length of message which can be sent over SMS">Minimum SMS Length</span></td>



                          <td>


                                      <div class="isDefault">Minimum SMS Length</div>
                                      <input id="policiesListMinimum SMS Length.policyValueViewsMinimum SMS Length.value" name="policiesList[Minimum SMS Length].policyValueViews[Minimum SMS Length].value" class="policyValueMap" disabled="disabled" type="text" value="1"/>

                          </td>
                      </tr>





                      <tr>

                          <td>



                                      <input class="configuredCheckBox" name="policiesList[Operation Set].configured" class="checkboxDefault" type="checkbox" value="true"/><input type="hidden" name="_policiesList[Operation Set].configured" value="on"/>


                          </td>
                          <td><span title="Allows service requests to specified operations only">Operation Set</span></td>



                          <td>



                                    <input id="checkbox" name="policiesList[Operation Set].policyValueViews[getSmsDeliveryStatus].valueAsBoolean" class="checkboxDefault" disabled="disabled" type="checkbox" value="true" checked="checked"/>
                                    <span class="isDefault">getSmsDeliveryStatus</span>
                                    <br/>


                                    <input id="checkbox" name="policiesList[Operation Set].policyValueViews[sendSms].valueAsBoolean" class="checkboxDefault" disabled="disabled" type="checkbox" value="true" checked="checked"/>
                                    <span class="isDefault">sendSms</span>
                                    <br/>



                                    <input id="checkbox" name="policiesList[Operation Set].policyValueViews[sendSmsLogo].valueAsBoolean" class="checkboxDefault" disabled="disabled" type="checkbox" value="true" checked="checked"/>
                                    <span class="isDefault">sendSmsLogo</span>
                                    <br/>

                                    <input id="checkbox" name="policiesList[Operation Set].policyValueViews[sendSmsRingtone].valueAsBoolean" class="checkboxDefault" disabled="disabled" type="checkbox" value="true" checked="checked"/>
                                    <span class="isDefault">sendSmsRingtone</span>
                                    <br/>


                          </td>
                      </tr>

                      <tr>

                          <td>



                                      <input class="configuredCheckBox" name="policiesList[Prepaid Charging Configuration].configured" class="checkboxDefault" type="checkbox" value="true"/><input type="hidden" name="_policiesList[Prepaid Charging Configuration].configured" value="on"/>


                          </td>
                          <td><span title="Prepaid Charging Configuration">Prepaid Charging Configuration</span></td>



                          <td>

                                      <div class="isDefault">account_label</div>

                                      <textarea id="policiesListPrepaid Charging Configuration.policyValueViewsaccount_label.value" name="policiesList[Prepaid Charging Configuration].policyValueViews[account_label].value" class="policyValueMap" disabled="disabled" rows="3" cols="20">PRIMARY</textarea>



                                      <div class="isDefault">account_type</div>
                                      <textarea id="policiesListPrepaid Charging Configuration.policyValueViewsaccount_type.value" name="policiesList[Prepaid Charging Configuration].policyValueViews[account_type].value" class="policyValueMap" disabled="disabled" rows="3" cols="20">STORED_VALUE</textarea>


                                      <div class="isDefault">sendSms</div>
                                      <textarea id="policiesListPrepaid Charging Configuration.policyValueViewssendSms.value" name="policiesList[Prepaid Charging Configuration].policyValueViews[sendSms].value" class="policyValueMap" disabled="disabled" rows="3" cols="20">10</textarea>

                          </td>

                      </tr>


                      <tr>

                          <td>



                                      <input class="configuredCheckBox" name="policiesList[Sender Address Blacklist].configured" class="checkboxDefault" type="checkbox" value="true"/><input type="hidden" name="_policiesList[Sender Address Blacklist].configured" value="on"/>


                          </td>
                          <td><span title="Forbids service requests with argument on a black list">Sender Address Blacklist</span></td>

                                      <div class="isDefault">Sender Address Blacklist</div>
                                      <textarea id="policiesListSender Address Blacklist.policyValueViewsSender Address Blacklist.value" name="policiesList[Sender Address Blacklist].policyValueViews[Sender Address Blacklist].value" class="policyValueMap" disabled="disabled" rows="3" cols="20"></textarea>

                          </td>
                      </tr>


                      <tr>

                          <td>

                                      <input class="configuredCheckBox" name="policiesList[Sender Address Whitelist].configured" class="checkboxDefault" type="checkbox" value="true"/><input type="hidden" name="_policiesList[Sender Address Whitelist].configured" value="on"/>
                          </td>
                          <td><span title="Forbids service requests with argument not on a white list">Sender Address Whitelist</span></td>

                          <td>

                                      <div class="isDefault">Sender Address Whitelist</div>
                                      <textarea id="policiesListSender Address Whitelist.policyValueViewsSender Address Whitelist.value" name="policiesList[Sender Address Whitelist].policyValueViews[Sender Address Whitelist].value" class="policyValueMap" disabled="disabled" rows="3" cols="20"></textarea>

                          </td>

                      </tr>

                </tbody>
              </table>
```